# Autofill the selected value in Chosen Multiselect for Edit form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

So i have a chosen multi select on my  add client form which is working fine and showing the dropdown list. Now i am able to select the value and saving into database. I have a option of edit client also in which i am fetching the value from database and using the same form to populate the value through model on a form. All the dropdown,and text box fills the value fine but i an not able to pre populate the value on Chosen Multiselect. I did this but it seem to not work.

```
var StudName = '@Model.StudentListText';
var StudDropDown = document.getElementById('StudentList');
StudDropDown.options[StudDropDown.selectedIndex].text = StudName.trim();
```

html

```
   <div class="editor-field">

            @Html.ListBox("StudentList", Model.Students

     , new

     {

         @class = "chzn-select",
          data_placeholder = "Choose  Student..."

     }
     )

         </div>
```

how to populate the chosen multiselect with value i have already saved in database?
I am using MVC 4.5 and C#.
Thanks in Advance.